# Responsive image is anchoring at the top of its cotainer div

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a webpage for mobile devices, in which I need to preview some images. The issue facing is when ever I change(decrease) the width of the window (obviously the image resizes and its height reduces keeping the aspect ratio) the image is sticking on the top of the `div` in which the image control is placed.The css property `vertical-align:middle;` is not working for this div.Also tried using  `line-height` property which is also not working.I need to align the image vertically centre

[image]

My markup is is

```
<div id="dvImgPreview" class="imagePreview" style="display:block;" runat="server">                       
      <asp:Image ID="ImgIPreview" runat="server" ImageUrl="" />
</div>
```

and css used for this is

```
.imagePreview{text-align:center;vertical-align:middle; margin:10px 10px 5px 10px;height:410px;background-color:#000;}
.imagePreview img{max-width:100%;}
```

The height of the div needed to be fixed as 410px

Comment: try setting `display:table-cell` instead of `display:block` [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9shxgpgc/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a height defined you can use

```
.imagePreview img{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to declare `position:relative;` on `.imagePreview`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b0e7beq0/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Your solution works in my site I had to include the "max-width:100%;" also for this to work perfect

Answer (score 0):

try padding style instead of vertical-align as "padding:50% 0;"